# Python IDE PyCharm won't print last line of code

Tags: python

I'm a complete newbie when it comes to coding, so I'm probably making a stupid mistake here. What I'm doing is following along with a Python For Beginners textbook and writing the 'Hello World' exercise. I added the variable 'name' to the code and called the variable in the very next line. However, the 
print('Hello', name) line of code I wrote would not print, even though my first line print('Hello, world') did print. [Here's a screenshot of the code run on the Python console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f84lI.png) There are no error codes, so I'm guessing I just incorrectly defined the variable, but I'm not sure.

Comment: First of all welcome! Please take the [tour] and read about [ask]. It is important to provide a [mre] **inside the question** itself. Not images or links to images. Lastly, you use the `input` function. This function - as its name suggests - is waiting for your input. Write anything in the console and press `Enter` and see what happens. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You need to hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> after Python prints `'Keenan'` to print the last line.

When you call `input(str)`, `str` is the prompt. Once python prints the prompt, it's waiting for an input and then <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

So logically speaking your code should be:

```
name = input("What's your name?:")
print('Hello', name)
```

Which will print:

```
What's your name?:
```

where you can type:

```
What's your name?: Keenan
```

followed by <kbd>Enter</kbd>